# Adding height of binary tree to insert method

Tags: java, insert, binary-tree, binary-search, tostring

I am creating a program that inserts a character (number/letter) into a binary tree. So far, I'm able to produce an output but it's not what I expected. These are the problems I'm encountering:

1. The `insert` method is not able to print the correct `height` of the tree. I am not sure where I should insert my `height++;` statement to get the correct output.
2. The `insert` method is only able to add nodes to the right.

> Expected Output: `ht=3 [K=3 L=[K=1 R=[K=2]] R=[K=5 L=[K=4]]]`

> My Output: `ht=4 [K=3 R=[K=1 R=[K=2 R=[K=5 R=[K=4]]]]`

*(all nodes are only added to the right 'R')*

**Here are my classes for reference:**

**Main Class**

```
BST<Character> bst = new BST<>();

bst.insert('3');
bst.insert('1');
bst.insert('2');
bst.insert('5');
bst.insert('4');

System.out.println("ht=" + bst.height + " " + bst.toString());
```

**BST Class** - where the `insert` method is declared

```
public class BST<T> extends BT<T> {
    // insert() method
    public void insert(char k) 
    {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new BTNode(k);
            return;
        }
        
        BTNode<T> n = root;
        BTNode<T> p = null; // parent
    
        while (n != null) {
            p = n;
            
            if (k < n.value) {
                n = n.left;
            } else {
                n = n.right;
            }
        }
        
        if (k < p.value) {
            p.left = new BTNode(k);
        } else {
            p.right = new BTNode(k);
            height++;   // adds 1 to height when a new level is made
        }
    }
}
```

**BTNode Class**

```
public class BTNode<T> {
    T info;
    int value, level;
    BTNode<T> left, right;
    
    public BTNode(T el) {
        this(el, null, null);
    }
    
    public BTNode(T el, BTNode<T> l, BTNode<T> r) {
        info = el;
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }
}
```

**BT Class** - where the `toString` method is declared

```
public class BT<T> {
    BTNode<T> root = null;
    int height = 0;
    
    public BT() {
        BTNode<T> node = new BTNode("");
    }
    
    // other methods
    
    // toString()
    public String toString() {
        return toString(root);
    }
    
    public String toString(BTNode<T> n) {
        String s = "";
        
        if (n == null) {
            return "";
        }
        
        if (n != null) {
            s = "[K=" + n.info;
            
            if (n.left != null) {
                s = s + " L=" + toString(n.left) + "]";
            }
            if (n.right != null) {
                s = s + " R=" + toString(n.right) + "]";
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

Hope you can help me out, thanks!

Comment: Step through your insert method with the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have quite a few issues in your code. I'll list a few immediate items but you really will need to learn to use an interactive debugger and unit testing to resolve the sorts of issues you are seeing.

1. You refer to the `value` field in `BTNode` in your comparison but it is never set. You should really be referring to `info` (which is the actual data in the node).
2. But given `info` is a generic type you can't use standard comparison operators. Instead you'll need to define it as `<T extends Comparable<T>>` and then use `n.info.compareTo(k) > 0`.
3. The key passed into insert should also be of type `T`
4. Which means the other classes also need to ensure `T` extends `Comparable`.
5. Height is only incremented when nodes are added to the right which makes no sense.

Height needs to be increased only when a node is inserted further from the root than the current maximum. Something like the following:

```
int depth = 0;
while (n != null) {
    depth++;
    p = n;
...
}

depth++;
if (depth > height)
    height = depth;
```

You should get used to making your fields private and accessing them through `getters`. In your case a `compareValue` method would likely make sense.

Comment: I was able to apply the `compareTo` method and it helped. Do you have any advice where I should put my `height++;` to get the total height of the binary tree? Thanks a lot for your detailed answer!

Comment: To calculate the height of the tree you need to keep a track of the depth of the current node during the insert. I'll add some code to my answer to show what I mean.